# Multiple Category Models vs Single Category Model with STI? - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many-through, single-table-inheritance

I have four models:

- Post
- Product
- Article
- Location

Each of these can have multiple Categories. The only logic rule is that the Categories are completely separate for each Class, so that a Post cannot have an ArticleCategory, a Location cannot have a ProductCatgory and so on.

**Option 1: Multiple Category Models**

Models:

- PostCategory
- ProductCategory
- ArticleCategory
- LocationCategory

Models for has_many through:

- PostCategorization
- ProductCategorization
- ArticleCategorization
- LocationCategorization

This works, but it doesn't adhere to the DRY (don't repeat yourself) philosophy. So, how about using STI?

**Option 2: Single Category Model with STI**

Models:

- Category
- Categorization

SubModels:

- PostCategory << Category
- ProductCategory << Category
- ArticleCategory << Category
- LocationCategory << Category

This seems fine, but I don't know if I need to even use STI if the columns are the same, and the logic is the same. The only difference between them is the associations.

**Option 3: Single Category Model without STI?**

Would it be better to have a "category_class" column, and do something like this:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :categories, -> { where category_class: "Post" }

end
```

To save on the number of classes and subclasses, and simplify the entire solution. I have used this before but not on something with polymorphic associations, would this work?

Comment: Perfect use-case for STI in my opinion. Especially when you are creating tables with exactly the same structure, you should be thinking STI. Ideally even namespacing them, so you can store them in a separate folder. Added benefit is that you can define validations on the `Category` model, so that the STI classes can be very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding. But, it seems to me...

You could use an `enum` to specify what each `Category` record categorizes. Something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: categories
#
#  id                :integer          not null, primary key
#  name              :string           not null
#  categorizes       :integer          not null
#  created_at        :datetime         not null
#  updated_at        :datetime         not null
#
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categorizeables, through: :categorizations

  enum categorizes: {
    post:         0,
    product:      1,
    article:      2,
    location:     3
  }

  class << self 

    def not_for(categorizeable_type)
      where.not(categorizes: categorizeable_type)
    end

  end

end
```

Then, you can use your polymorphic join model, `Categorization` Something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: categorizations
#
#  id                   :integer          not null, primary key
#  category_id          :integer          not null
#  categorizeable_id    :integer          not null
#  categorizeable_type  :string           not null
#  created_at           :datetime         not null
#  updated_at           :datetime         not null
#
class Categorization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :categorizeable, polymorphic: true
end
```

And then you can associate your `categorizations` and `categories` using a `has :many, through`:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: posts
#
#  id                   :integer          not null, primary key
#  created_at           :datetime         not null
#  updated_at           :datetime         not null
#
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations, as: :categorizeable
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations

  validate :correct_categorization

  def correct_categorization
    if categories.not_for(:post).any?
      errors.add(:categorization, "is incorrect")
    end
  end

end
```

I added that validation since you stated "Categories are completely separate for each Class". You may need to fiddle with that a bit, but hopefully it gives you an idea of how it might work.

Comment: Interesting approach, but I'm having some doubts whether the validation rule adheres to the separation of concerns principle. Now a `Post` has to be aware of the structure of `Category` to determine whether the category is correct,.. I think STI is the better approach here.

Comment: After giving it some thought... it isn't that bad, since both ends of the relationship should otherwise be polymorphic, which complicates things. Wouldn't it be better to scope the association instead?

Comment: @bo-oz - Fair enough on the separation of concerns. Although, it is easy enough remove the need for `Post` to be aware of the structure of `Category` (see updated answer). What do you have in mind when you say "scope the association"?

Comment: see my answer which I just wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I think @jvillian made a great suggestion to use a enum in this case. However, I do not particularly like the validation rule... a user shouldn't see categories that don't belong to the object he's trying to categorize. I would create a scoped relationship in this case, so I would define the `Post` model like this:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations, as: :categorizeable
  has_many :categories, -> { where(categorizes: 0)}, through: :categorizations
end
```

And build the association through the has_many through relation:

```
f.association :categories
```

Comment: TBH, I have never used scopes on associations. So, out of curiosity, if the OP tries to do something like `@post.categories << @some_non_post_category`, will this throw an error or somehow complain or otherwise allow the OP to know that a non-post category has been assigned to a post?

Comment: It should give a record not found error I guess... but I would suggest OP to test its behavior...

Comment: TBH, I haven't thought of using ENUM for this kind of classification... so I guess we both learned something new today. Great collaboration :)